# How do I loop through a div in a Foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I have a Foreach loop that loops through an image grid block on my wordpress website. Everything is working fine but, I wanted to add a popup window so that it opens up whenever I click on images.

As you can see in below screenshot, the image, heading, body, full name and email are all looping correctly. However, the information inside my modal (popup window) isn't looping correctly. It shows 'Heading - 1 and Body - 1' whenever I click on image 2 instead of 'Heading - 2 & Body - 2'.

The two 'popup-heading-grid' and 'popup-body-grid' is looping correctly on its own as you can see, however, it doesn't loop when its inside the div with class 'modal'.

My questions is how do I get the Foreach to loop through the last chunck of div (the one with id="modal2") so that It correctly shows 'Heading - 2 & Body - 2' in the popup window when i click on the second image.

`

```
<div class='bounds bounds-collapse image-grid <?= ($block['contain_size']) ? 'ig-contain' : ''; ?> <?= ($block['heading_colour'] == 'black') ? 'ig-black-heading' : ''; ?> <?= $bg_colour; ?>'>
    <div class='align' >
        <?php if (!empty($block['heading'])) { ?>
            <h2><?= $block['heading']; ?></h2>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class='ig-columns ani-all' >
            <?php foreach($block['columns'] as $column) { $icon = (!empty($column['email_address'])); ?><div class='ig-column <?= ($icon) ? 'ig-icon-pad' : ''; ?>' >
                
                <div data-modal-target="#modal2" class='ig-image image ' style='background-image: url(<?= $column['image']['sizes']['large']; ?>'>
                    <?php if (!empty($block['tint'])) { ?>
                        <div class='ig-image-tint middle'></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                
                <?= $column['popup-heading-grid']; ?>
                <?= $column['popup-body-grid']; ?>
                
                <?php if ($icon) { ?>
                    <a href='mailto:<?= $column['email_address']; ?>?subject=Website%20Enquiry'><img class='ig-icon' src='<?= SITE()->resource('artwork/mail.svg'); ?>'></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?= $column['text']; ?>

                
                 <div class="modal" id="modal2">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <div class="title"><?= $column['popup-heading-grid']; ?></div>
                        <button data-close-button class="close-button">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <?= $column['popup-body-grid']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
            </div><?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

`

Here is my Javascript function for the modal popup:

```
 const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
    openModal(modal)
  })
})

overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active')
  modals.forEach(modal => {
    closeModal(modal)
  })
})

closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = button.closest('.modal')
    closeModal(modal)
  })
})

function openModal(modal) {
  if (modal == null) return
  modal.classList.add('active')
  overlay.classList.add('active')
}

function closeModal(modal) {
  if (modal == null) return
  modal.classList.remove('active')
  overlay.classList.remove('active')
}
```

[Here is the screenshot of the popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnB2A.png)

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't use the same `id="modal2"` each time through the loop.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for addressing that. Now how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: One simple fix would be increment the id in your loop

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not entirely sure on how to increment the id in my loop as I'm very new to PHP, if anyone can do it for me, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Outside the loop `$ctr = 0;` ... inside the loop `$ctr++` and `id="modal<?=$ctr?>"` and same for the `data-modal-target`

Comment: @charlietfl I finally got it to work! thank you so much for your help! you made my day!